# Foundation (3) Navigation Stretch 100% width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I was wondering if it's possible to have the Foundation 3 by Zurb navigation bar items be centered when the bar stretches all the way across the screen. I have 6 items on the navigation and they are all right up to the right side.

```
<ul class="nav-bar">
   <!-- nav items... ect --> 
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make even items but I managed to make it look much better, try this CSS for Foundation:

```
.nav-bar {  background: inherit; }
.nav-bar > li { background: #4d4d4d; border: 1px solid #333333; }
.nav-bar li {
    float: left;
}
.nav-bar > li > a:first-child {  padding: 0 12px; font-size: 14px; }
.nav-bar > li:last-child { border-right: 0px; -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset; box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset; }

.nav-bar > li:hover { background: #666; }
```